# How to close Firebase Crashlytic Issue?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

It seems Firebase Crashlytic in console page got a drastic UI change.

First how can one add notes to each crash report?

Second how to close an issue when it is already fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a permissions issue. I went through a tour of Firebase with my team the other day and they reported saying their UI did not include what I was showing them. I found they had been onboarded as Viewers and not Editors and as a result they were unable to close issues and add notes.

Comment: I am the owner so that should not be the case, however it seems this issue is already fixed. The close and mute option is now showing. Probably a legit bug when they are implementing the dark mode which is now available in the console.